# wordpress redirection loop after login

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have created a custom post taxonomy called portfolio so such posts have an url like this: mydomain.com/portfolio/post-name/. This is fine so far however i just found I am having a problem with my Wordpress login and i believe this is causing it. I have a login link on every post so if a user log in from there it is supposed to be redirected to the post page but instead i get a redirection loop error.

If you look at the URL which Wordpress is trying to redirect to you will see something like mydomain.com//post-name/ so it means the taxonomy name is missing from the URL and thats causing the redirection error.

How can i address this problem and have the redirection fixed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to Previous Page After Login
Add the following code in your function.php it would help.

```
    if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') || (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location'])) ) {
        add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
        function my_login_redirect() {
            $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            wp_safe_redirect($location);
            exit();


}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried your code but it didnt work. I dont know why but im still being redirected to that endless loop page.

Comment: You mean everything what i have in function.php?

Comment: yes can you email me what your problem with in detail at skksandy91@gmail.com